# У меня ошибка когда вызываю функцию который внутри себя имеет еще одну функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Код:

```
def list_box():
    num = 87 
    def inner_box():
       num_2 = 65 
       print(num+num_2)

list_box(inner_box())
```

Ошибка:

```
list_box(inner_box())
NameError: name 'inner_box' is not defined
```

Как это исправить.
Как вызвать внутри функции еще одну функцию

Comment: Можешь повторить в коде. Я не шарю в этом .

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ!

Comment: для спасибо кнопка есть

Comment: @Atabekdemurtaza, я перенес комментарии в ответ, если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым.

Comment: Вообще, вы не отметили принятым ни один ответ ни на один из ваших вопросов. Рекомендую почитать: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вложенные функции не доступны по имени снаружи "родительских" функций. Чтобы вызвать внутреннюю функцию, можно дописать внутри внешней функции вызов внутренней функции (вариант 1), можно вернуть внутреннюю функцию из внешней функции через `return`, потом снаружи это значение вызвать как функцию (вариант 2) - все зависит от того, что конкретно вы пытаетесь сделать.

```
# Вариант 1
def list_box():
    num = 87 
 
    def inner_box():
       num_2 = 65 
       print(num+num_2)
 
    inner_box() 
 
 
list_box()  # вывод: 152
 
 
# Вариант 2
def list_box():
    num = 87 
 
    def inner_box():
       num_2 = 65 
       print(num+num_2)
 
    return inner_box
 
 
list_box()()  # вывод: 152

# В отдельных строках, чтобы было понятно, что тут происходит:
function = list_box()
function()
```

https://ideone.com/FKQ5jO

Comment: Теоретически (да и практически) прямой вызов вложенной функции таки возможен.

Comment: @GrAnd но таки не нужно так делать.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем ответ на поставленный вопрос, просто информации для...

Если по каким-то причинам всё-таки нужно вызвать вложенную функцию напрямую (без задействования "родительской") - это возможно. Но для этого как минимум нужно заново переопределить локальные переменные "родительской" функции которые используются во вложенной.

Пример того, как это возможно сделать:

```
def list_box():
    num = 87 
    def inner_box(x):
       num_2 = 65 
       print(f'num = {num}\nnum_2 = {num_2}\nx = {x}\nnum+num_2*x = {num+num_2*x}')


# а теперь - "грязные хаки" :)
import types 

def call_nested(outer, inner_name, **vars):
    def var_wrap(val):
        def var_closure():
            return val
        return var_closure.__closure__[0]

    for code in outer.__code__.co_consts:
        if isinstance(code, types.CodeType) and code.co_name == inner_name:
            return types.FunctionType(code, globals(), None, None, tuple(var_wrap(vars[name]) for name in code.co_freevars))

call_nested(list_box, 'inner_box', num=11)(2)
```

Вывод:

```
num = 11
num_2 = 65
x = 2
num+num_2*x = 141
```

Comment: Чет сложно, можно было просто `global inner_box` добавить)

Answer (score 2):

**Вот решение**

```
def list_box():
    num = 87
    def inner_box():

        num2 = 65
        print(num+num2)
    return inner_box()


list_box()
```

Comment: Это фактически совпадает с первым вариантом из моего ответа, только у меня не `return inner_box()`, а просто `inner_box()` - но в `return` в данном случае нет смысла, т.к. внутренняя функция ничего не возвращает.